# How can I cut the 3rd line from java -version?

Tags: linux, sed, cut, tail

To preface this, yes, I have already searched for ways to do this with cut, sed, and tail. However, I have found that none of the traditional ways of obtaining the third line of an output work.

```
java -version | sed 3p
java -version | tail -1
java -version | cut -d$'\n' -f3
```

All of these commands simply return the same thing as

```
java -version
```

What's going on here? How can I get only the third line?

Comment: Your output is going to standard error not standard output. You need to redirect standard error to the pipe too.

Comment: `java -version 2>&1 | ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java -version 2>&1 | tail -1
```